# Can I read other language and speak with TTS such as " Bengali " ,"Hindi "

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Android is providing a cool feature (from Android 1.6) called Text to Speech (TTS) which speaks the text in different languages. I have written a code on TTS. It is working fine. But now I want to set Language of TTS to "Bengali ". But TTS currently does not support "Bengali". Is there any way to set Language of TTS  to "Bengali" .

```
 tts = new TextToSpeech(TextToSpeechSultan.this,new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

            public void onInit(int status)
            {
                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR)
                {
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);


                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately *Bengali* or *Hindi* is not supported by Android. See the list of Locales supported below

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Many other languages are also not supported by the looks of it.

Comment: What can I do to support this language ?